# Rails Admin comes up empty on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-admin

I'm trying to use Rails Admin on heroku.  It works perfectly in both production and development, but when I try to access /admin through heroku, the Dashboard renders completely empty(it has the basic Rails Admin scaffolding, but none of my content).  The rest of the site is working fine.  There are no errors in heroku logs, which look like this:

```
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/admin/" for 76.93.177.75 at 2013-01-03 09:05:48 +0000
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard as HTML
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.0.3/app/views/rails_admin/main/dashboard.html.haml within layouts/rails_admin/application (0.3ms)
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.0.3/app/views/layouts/rails_admin/_secondary_navigation.html.haml (1.3ms)
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.0.3/app/views/layouts/rails_admin/pjax.html.haml (2.1ms)
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 17.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/admin/ host=rocky-oasis-1876.herokuapp.com fwd=76.93.177.75 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=12ms service=43ms status=200 bytes=2603
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/rails_admin/rails_admin-b54745219c9cfcf789963ed61310c222.css host=rocky-oasis-1876.herokuapp.com fwd=76.93.177.75 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=29ms status=200 bytes=129747
2013-01-03T09:05:48+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/rails_admin/rails_admin-713b6f759f0edf80a0c69b3ced027e1e.js host=rocky-oasis-1876.herokuapp.com fwd=76.93.177.75 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=34ms status=200 bytes=283158
2013-01-03T09:05:49+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/glyphicons-halflings-f6675c325532ec11a984d58e172b8e2a.png host=rocky-oasis-1876.herokuapp.com fwd=76.93.177.75 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=13826
```

I'm not sure what else to include, since everything is "working".  I am using rails 3.2.9 and
rails_admin 0.0.3, and the up-to-date heroku toolbelt.  If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not alone.  I had this, too, and it seems others have.  The solution that worked for me was to upgrade rails_admin.  This works because fixes have been committed to rails_admin in later versions; here's a link:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/pull/1184

This pull request went in after version 0.0.3, which you say you are using, so I think upgrading will help you.

```
bundle update rails_admin
```

After you do this, remember to commit your Gemfile.lock, precompile assets (if you normally do this, it depends on your set up) and run your tests before you deploy.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark, but thanks!  This seems to work : )